Qt 6.8 Protobuf serialization default values to Json
I have a message in proto file
message GeoCoord
{
    double      lat = 1; 
    double      lon = 2;
}

After serialization this message to json and sending it with WebSocket on other socket i getting not set values, while operating default values.
Common case of using Qt Protobuf:
QProtobufJsonSerializer serializer_json;
GeoCoord geo;
geo.setLat(1.1);
geo.setLon(2.2);
QByteArray message = geo.serialize(&serializer_json);
socket->send(message)

After that in another socket we have a message
{"geoCoords":{"lat":1.1,"lon":2.2}}
and this is what i expected. But if i try set default double value 0:
geo.setLat(0);
geo.setLon(0);

the message is {"geoCoords":{}}. It would be ok, if i dont set them at all like:
GeoCoord geo;
QByteArray message = geo.serialize(&serializer_json);

Is there normal way to operate with default values? I know that for double one can set '-0', but in other messages i have int values.

I think problem is that build in types in protobut can't be "empty". This means that if you not set lat and then check protobuf value it will contain 0 (there is not way to verify that it is empty).
As a result QProtobufJsonSerializer is unable to tell if values has not been set or has been set to 0. I do not see there is an option to reconfigure QProtobufJsonSerializer, so it will externalize zero values for build in types.

It would be useful to know what version of Protobufs you're using: 2, or 3?
In version 3, every field in a message is optional. In your case, that would mean that there is a very distinct difference between a message having lat and lon set to 0 and a message where they're never set. As you say, the output would be understandable if you'd not set them at all.
So, I think you've run into a bug in someone else's code.
It looks like QT has built its own code generator. Are you using qt_add_protobuf in your cmake for QT, or are you calling qtprotobufgen to generate QT classes from your .proto file?
Things to Try
1) One or Both Fields?
Try setting only lat to 0, see what comes out then.
2) Generated Code understands options fields?
It would be interesting to take a look at the generated code for the GeoCoord class, see if the two fields have methods or properties a bit like has_lat(), or has_lon(). Such methods would be generated by the C++ code generator in standard use of Google's protoc, and are used to indicate whether a field has indeed been set. If QT's generated code has such methods, then at least it is aware that the fields are optional. That in turn would reinforce the likelihood that there's something amiss in QProtobufJsonSerializer.
3) Compare to Ordinary Google protoc Generated Code
It would also be interesting for you to compare the result to that which you get from using Google's protoc to generate their C++ class implementations, see if that behaves as expected.
4) Other reasons to use ordinary Google protoc Generated Code
It looks like QT is using this anyway, with the addition of a plug-in which I'm assuming is there to support QT's own data types such as QPoint. I don't know why they've done this; the whole point of protobufs is to allow data interchange between different languages on different platforms, and the QT data types aren't going to mean anything to anything other than C++/QT. QT already has its own entirely separate serialisation library for QT-QT interchange.
I mention this because if the problem is within QT's extensive wrappers around Google's vanilla C++ implementation, you can probably just use Google's generated code "as is". It might not integrate into the development project quite so seamlessly, but it might be that is what you have to do to get things working.

This is the normal behavior of Protobuf.
Google protobuf library does have a way to overcome this by using JsonPrintOptions and set always_print_primitive_fields to true.
I did not find something similar in Qt code.
